# OLED display application for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, raspberry-pi

Python script to output status information to a small OLED screen connected to a Raspberry Pi.

I'm relatively new at writing python so although the app works and outputs correct information it is far from the clean code I encountered when looking at other people's code.

I think I covered most of PEP8. I am most interested in code structure, 'the python way', refactoring and cleanup.

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
#
# | file       :   showStats.py
# | version    :   V1.0
# | date       :   2018-10-01
# | function   :   Show statistics on Waveshare 1.5inch OLED
# |                 To preserve OLED screen life the display is turned off unless
# |                 motion is detected in the server room. (via MQTT).
# |                 - Listens on MQTT topic
# |                     + home/basement/serverroom/motionsensor
#
# Requires psUtil.   Install:   sudo apt-get python-psutil
# Requires pahoMQTT. Install:   sudo apt install python-pip
#                               pip install paho-mqtt
#
# INFO:
# Collects various information about the system and displays the info on the screen
#

# Logging
import logging
import logging.config
import commands
import os
import psutil
import platform
import datetime
import time
# MQTT
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
# RPI
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
# specific to OLED screen
import DEV_Config
import OLED_Driver
import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont
import ImageColor

# CONSTANTS
LOGGING_CONFIG_FILE = "logging_config.ini"
MQTT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC = "home/basement/serverroom/motionsensor"
MQTT_BROKER = ("192.168.1.170", 1883, 60)  # (host, port, timeout)
REFRESH_INTERVAL = 2  # seconds


#GLOBAL
OLED = None
mqtt_client = None
show_on_screen = False


# Logging setup
logging.config.fileConfig(fname=LOGGING_CONFIG_FILE, disable_existing_loggers=True)
logger = logging.getLogger()


try:
    def main():
        logging.addLevelName(100, 'START')
        logging.log(100, "============================")
        logging.log(100, "STARTING UP")

        logger.info("Initialize OLED screen")
        global OLED
        OLED = OLED_Driver.OLED()
        oled_scan_dir = OLED_Driver.SCAN_DIR_DFT  # SCAN_DIR_DFT = D2U_L2R
        OLED.OLED_Init(oled_scan_dir)
        OLED.OLED_Clear()
        DEV_Config.Driver_Delay_ms(500)

        global mqtt_client
        mqtt_client = paho.Client(client_id="RPI-A_OLEDScreen", clean_session=False, userdata=None)
        mqtt_client.enable_logger(logger)
        mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
        mqtt_client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
        mqtt_client.on_message = on_message
        mqtt_client.connect(MQTT_BROKER[0], MQTT_BROKER[1], MQTT_BROKER[2])
        mqtt_client.loop_start()

        logger.info("Setting up OLED display area")
        DEV_Config.Driver_Delay_ms(500)
        image = Image.new("L", (OLED.OLED_Dis_Column, OLED.OLED_Dis_Page), 0)  # grayscale (luminance)
        ImageDraw.Draw(image)  # draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

        logger.info("Fetch platform info once@startup")
        os_name, name, version, _, _, _ = platform.uname()
        boot_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(psutil.boot_time())
        mac_address = get_mac_address('eth0')
        logging.log(100, "OS: " + os_name)
        logging.log(100, "Device name: " + name)
        logging.log(100, "version: " + version)
        logging.log(100, "Logging config file: " + LOGGING_CONFIG_FILE)
        logging.log(100, "============================")

        while True:
            update_display(os_name, name, version, boot_time, mac_address, show_on_screen)
            time.sleep(REFRESH_INTERVAL)  # seconds


    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        logger.info("CONNACK received with code %d." % rc)
        client.subscribe(MQTT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC, qos=1)


    def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
        logger.info("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))


    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        global show_on_screen
        logger.info(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.qos) + " " + str(msg.payload))
        if msg.topic == MQTT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC and msg.payload == "motion":
            show_on_screen = True
        else:
            show_on_screen = False


    def update_display(os_name, name, version, boot_time, mac_address, show_on_screen):
        if not show_on_screen:
            OLED.OLED_Clear()
            return
        else:
            ip_address = None
            fs_total, fs_used, fs_free, fs_percent = (None, None, None, None)

            # update values every loop
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            cpu_percent = str(psutil.cpu_percent()) + "%"  # first run gives a wrong value due to CPU load while initializing PSUTIL
            cpu_temp = get_cpu_temperature()

            # update every hour
            if current_time.minute % 59:
                ip_address = commands.getoutput('hostname -I')

            if current_time.hour % 23:
                # update every day
                fs_total, fs_used, fs_free, fs_percent = psutil.disk_usage("/")

            # temporary debug code. Replace with 'draw.text()' and 'draw.line()'
            print(os_name, name, version)
            print("Local IP address: " + ip_address)
            print("MAC: " + mac_address)
            print("CPU %:", cpu_percent)
            print("CPU temp:", cpu_temp)
            print(sizeof_fmt(fs_used), "of", sizeof_fmt(fs_total), "(", fs_percent, "%)")
            print("up time:", friendly_time_delta(boot_time, current_time))
            logger.info("Done updating OLED screen")

    # Return friendly TimeDelta string
    # Example: "4 days, 8 hours 2 minutes"
    def friendly_time_delta(start, end=datetime.datetime.now()):
        up_time = end - start
        years, reminder = divmod(up_time.total_seconds(), 31556926)
        days, reminder = divmod(reminder, 86400)
        hours, reminder = divmod(reminder, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(reminder, 60)
        ret = ""
        if years > 1:
            ret = str(int(years)) + " years, "
        elif years == 1:
            ret = "1 year, "
        if days > 1:
            ret += str(int(days)) + " days, "
        elif days == 1:
            ret += "1 day, "
        if hours > 1:
            ret += str(int(hours)) + " hours"
        elif hours == 1:
            ret += str(int(hours)) + " hour"
        if ret == "" and minutes > 0:
            ret += str(int(minutes)) + " minutes"
        if ret == "" and seconds > 0:
            ret += str(int(seconds)) + " seconds"
        return ret


    # Return the MAC address of the specified interface
    def get_mac_address(interface='eth0'):
        try:
            raw_address = open('/sys/class/net/%s/address' % interface).read()
        except:
            raw_address = "00:00:00:00:00:00"
        return raw_address[0:17]


    # return friendly byte size string.
    # Example: 1024 -> 1KiB
    def sizeof_fmt(num, suffix='B'):
        for unit in ['', 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Gi', 'Ti', 'Pi', 'Ei', 'Zi']:
            if abs(num) < 1024.0:
                return "%3.1f%s%s" % (num, unit, suffix)
            num /= 1024.0
        return "%.1f%s%s" % (num, 'Yi', suffix)


    # Return CPU temperature as a character string
    def get_cpu_temperature():
        res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
        return res.replace("temp=", "").replace("'C\n", "")


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logger.info("exiting program")
except:
    logger.error('Exception occurred', exc_info=True)
    raise
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()  # this ensures a clean exit
    mqtt_client.loop_stop()
```

Comment: Please check your indentation. The easiest way to post code is to paste it into the question editor, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.